# RowSorter of JTable not sorting Integers correctly (1,10,100...2,20...3)

Tags: java, excel, swing, sorting, jtable

I'm pretty new to Java and I have tried excessively solving the problem on my own all day, but it doesn't to work. I'm trying to write a Java application that connects with an Excel sheet and allows via GUI to insert/save/sort data suitable for a movie database. Here is the code from the classe, where the GUI-magic and the sorting happens:

```
    package gui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

import object.Film;
import excel.Excelverbindung;

public class Tabelle extends JTable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static String[] columnNames = { "Nr.", "Titel", "Jahr", "Regie",
            "Primäres Genre", "Sekundäres Genre", "Wertung", "Originaltitel" };
    static List<Film> rowlist = new ArrayList<Film>();
    static String[] rowData = {};
    JTable table = new JTable();
    Excelverbindung excelverb = new Excelverbindung();

    public Tabelle() {
    }

    private List<Film> getRowData() {
        Excelverbindung excelverb = new Excelverbindung();
        rowlist = excelverb.leseExcel();
        return rowlist;
    }

    public JTable fuellenTabelle() {
        TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>();
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        sorter.setModel(tableModel);
        table.setModel(tableModel);

        Tabelle.rowlist = getRowData();
        String[] film = new String[7];

        for (Film temp : rowlist) {
            film[0] = temp.getNummer();
            film[1] = temp.getName();
            film[2] = temp.getJahr();
            film[3] = temp.getRegie();
            film[4] = temp.getGenre1();
            film[5] = temp.getGenre2();
            film[6] = temp.getWertung();
            ((DefaultTableModel) tableModel).addRow(film);
        }

        System.out.println("Tabelle erzeugt");
        return table;
    }

    public void getRandomFilm() {
        Film film;
        excelverb.oeffneVerbindung();
        film = excelverb.holeZufaelligerFilm();
        excelverb.schließeVerbindung();

        film.getNummer();
        film.getName();
        film.getJahr();
        film.getRegie();
        film.getGenre1();
        film.getGenre2();
        film.getWertung();
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Ach, egal...");
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "Nächster!");

        int input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null,
                "Nr.:" + film.getNummer() + " Titel: " + film.getName()
                        + " Jahr: " + film.getJahr() + " Genres: "
                        + film.getGenre1() + " und " + film.getGenre2()
                        + " von " + film.getRegie(),
                "Schau einfach den Film...", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

        if (input == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            getRandomFilm();
        } else if (input == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that RowSorter can't sort the String values (nummer is also a String), that I got. But even converting the Strings to Integer (I reversed my progress today to the last "runable" state of the code, hence the String Arrays) doesn't solve it. I came across the whole getClass and setting them to Integer.Class and so forth, but can't wrap my head around how to use it exactly. Either way, all it does is allow a sorting based on the String- not the nummeric value of the cell contents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, related topics I read were either very hard for me to follow or didn't cover my specific proble.

So, please be patient since English is neither my native tongue, nor am I very skilled in Java.

Thanks a bunch and best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the table what type of data is being stored in each column so the proper Comparator can be used to do the sorting.

You do this by overriding the `getColumnClass()` method of your TableModel (or JTable if you don't have access to the TableModel when it is created). Something like:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
    if (column == 3)
        return Integer.class;
    else
        return String.class;
}
```

Also, make sure you store `Integer` objects in the `TableModel`, not just a String representation of an Integer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, man, it worked like a charm. I created a new Integer Object ( `int zahl = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(temp.getNummer())); `) and implemented your snippet of code and voila. 

Just another question: why does the same method not work for the float numbers?    `double wertung = new Double(Double.parseDouble(temp.getWertung()));`
gives me a "Source not found" error...

Comment: No idea why a double doesn't work for you. It works fine for me.

Comment: But I could insert another condition into the if-clause, for example `if (column == 3) return Integer.class; else if (column == 6) return Double.class` for it to work, right? And I'd invoke the method twice, once with 0 as parameter, the other time with 6. Casting the temp.getWertung from String to Double should do the trick then, doesn't it? Sorry if I am missing out on something...

Comment: @Prometheus, yes that is the point of the getColumnClass() method. You return the class of the column. Every column could potentially be a different class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **Comparator** for **sorter** object like this:

```
    sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
      public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
          int len1 = o1.toString().length();
          int len2 = o2.toString().length();
          if (len1==len2) {
              return o1.compareTo(o2);
          } else {
              return len1-len2;
          }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, camickrs proposal did the trick tho. :)