# JTable sorting integer column inccorectly

Tags: java, swing, sorting, integer, jtable

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tblProduct.getModel());
tblProduct.setRowSorter(sorter);

List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(6, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
```

It is sorting it in order by the first number of the integer rather than the whole number, what is the easiest way of fixing this?

i.e. output like:

```
9
8
8
5
2
17
12
1
```

Comment: Suggests also that you have a 'wrong' model. The column contains a `String` and not `Integer`

Comment: Unfortunately, I rarely work with `JTables`.  I would guess you either need to change the model for the sort column to Integer like [g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se) intimated, or find a way to alter the comparator (if possible) to convert the String to an Integer for sorting purposes.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), will show you how to use JTables.

Comment: You need to: 1) store Integer objects in the model and 2) override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the model  to tell the table what the class of each column of data contains. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026013/rowsorter-of-jtable-not-sorting-integers-correctly-1-10-100-2-20-3/34026490#34026490